# Should django render_to_string response be used in innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, django

Let me start by saying that this is my first Django project, so consider the possibility that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.

I'm working on a webpage that will show a report in an HTML table.  I think the process I'm using to get the data and build the table is too complicated.  It works, but I think there is probably a better way.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

At this point I have a Django project that consists of a single web page and the basic Django infrastructure.  That page presents the user with some options to control a report and a button to start report generation.

When the report generation is initiated, an XMLHTTPRequest is made to a url that is routed (via Django) to a view.  That view calls an API to retrieve data and does some Python processing of the data.  Then it calls the render_to_string function with the data and a template that uses django_tables2 to render a table.  It returns the render_to_string response (wrapped in an HttpResponse) to the report web page.

The report web page sets the tables innerHTML to the XMLHTTPRequest responseText.

Here is the flow in a more succint version:

1. User clicks "Generate Report"
2. Report page makes an XMLHTTPRequest that is routed to a view.
3. View downloads data from the API, does some moderately complicated processing of it in Python, and renders it to a string using the render_to_string call and django_tables2.
4. The view returns the render_from_data response (the table HTML).
5. The report web page sets the table's innerHTML = the XMLHTTPRequest responseText.

That seems convoluted to me, but it is the easiest way I've found to generate the table.  The data returned  from the API needs to be re-structured before it is suitable for a report. It's easier to do in Python, so that's why the view is used to do the re-structuring.

Thanks in advance.

The Django template that generates the table html:

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
{% render_table report_details %}
```

The html code that loads the url to get the table html:

```
    <div><table id=report visibility="none"></table></div>
    <body>
        <script>

                function load_table ()
                {
                        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
                        {
                                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
                                {
                                        table_element = document.getElementById ("report");
                                        table_element.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                                        table_element.style.visibility = "visible";
                                }
                        };
                        xhttp.open("GET", "http://host:8000/reports/get_report_table", true);
                        xhttp.send();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a better way to do this.

The table rendering template goes inside an "% if %" block.  That  "% if %" block is only executed if the report data is available.

```
{% if generate_report %}
{% render_table report_details %}
{% endif %}
```

When the operator clicks the "Generate Report"  button, the code sets some parameters (basically report filters) and executes:

```
window.location.search = date_filter + "&" + filter + "generate_report=true";
```

The url route  / view for the original report page handles retrieving and formatting the report data if the "generate_report" parameter is true.

This removes the need for:

1. The XMLHTTPRequest to get the report data.
2. The URL route for routing the call to get the table data.
3. A second "view" for constructing the table data.
4. Setting the innerHTML value.

I'm sure there is room for improvement.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks.